# Get extent on every zoom or pan of map

Tags: openlayers, zoom

```
map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())
```

I am able to get extent using the above but I want the extent on every zoom/pan of map.. do we have any functions that can do it? i looked at zoom interactions and zoom to extent but none of those do what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
map.on('moveend', function() {
    var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())
});
```

as suggested by [M.Moraca](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368862/24989)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is this:

```
map.on('moveend', function() {
    var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())
});
```

Thanks the indications from @TomazicM [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/369068/72195)