# Filter geometry based on map extent using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, filter, json

I need to summarize an attribute of a geojson based on the map extent. I want to sum values for all features intersecting bbox. I think that I must use the [Bbox filter](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_filter_Bbox-Bbox.html) but isn't clear for me how I can use it.

I've a simple GeoJSON with four geometry named `test_data.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test_data",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "name": "focusarea-id1", "pop": 30 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 10.224194550042373, 41.358221559689788 ], [ 10.224194550042373, 42.154498393805234 ], [ 11.816748218273265, 42.154498393805234 ], [ 11.816748218273265, 41.358221559689788 ], [ 10.224194550042373, 41.358221559689788 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "name": "focusarea-id2", "pop": 20 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 11.960078048414047, 40.779593726899229 ], [ 11.960078048414047, 41.87314724575112 ], [ 13.297823129727995, 41.87314724575112 ], [ 13.297823129727995, 40.779593726899229 ], [ 11.960078048414047, 40.779593726899229 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "name": "focusarea-id1", "pop": 10 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 11.519471533536832, 42.425232517404488 ], [ 11.519471533536832, 43.582488182985607 ], [ 12.8890676882154, 43.582488182985607 ], [ 12.8890676882154, 42.425232517404488 ], [ 11.519471533536832, 42.425232517404488 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "name": "focusarea-id3", "pop": 40 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 13.043014542811051, 42.255360126126526 ], [ 13.043014542811051, 43.465700913981998 ], [ 13.871142450291117, 43.465700913981998 ], [ 13.871142450291117, 42.255360126126526 ], [ 13.043014542811051, 42.255360126126526 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

I'm be able to put on the map my four rectangles using this code:

```
var sourceDataUrl = '{% static 'gis-data/vettori/test_data.geojson' %}';
var polygonsSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: sourceDataUrl,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});
var vectors = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: polygonsSource,
});
map.addLayer(vectors);

var fetchFn = fetch(sourceDataUrl)
  .then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
  });

/// Summarize pop
fetchFn.then(function(json) {
    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection(),
    });

    var polygonPop = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++) {
      polygonPop += features[i].values_.pop;
    }
    console.log(polygonPop);

});

/// Compute the bounding box based on map extent
map.getView().on('change', function() {
    var extent3857 = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())
    var extent4326 = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent3857, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    console.log('Boundary Box 4326: '+extent4326);

});
```

I can compute the bounding box based on map extent but I don't understand how I can link this feature with `polygonSurface`.

**EDIT 1 with the indications of @Mike**

```
map.getView().on('change', function() {

    var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(
      map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()),
      'EPSG:3857',
      'EPSG:4326',
    );

    var polygonIntersection = [];

    polygonsSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {
      console.log(feature);
      polygonIntersection.push(feature);
    });

    console.log(polygonIntersection); // response -> Array []

});
```

Using the method `forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` I've an empty array.

Comment: What would the filtering algorithm be? Sum values for all features intersecting bbox? Sum values for all features completely inside bbox? Calculate actual feature surface  visible inside bbox? Please edit the question and add this info.

Comment: I've edit my question @TomazicM

Comment: Next question: In your code you calculate extent only when zoom changes, but what about map panning? Feature intersections with bbox change also when you pan/move the map.

Comment: Oh! You pointed me out that my code is usefull only with zoom in/out. I was sure that was usefull also with pan/move. This is a problem that I've not considerd before...

Comment: This is a my misunderstand because I consider the extent of the map and not the extent as an object from one ore more action.

Comment: I've used this solution for calculate the map extent https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287450/72195

Comment: I've found the solution for pan/move and I've edit my question @TomazicM

Comment: If you add your features to a vector source you can use `forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent`
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent
If you only have point features it would be more efficient to use `forEachFeatureInExtent` or `getFeaturesInExtent`

Comment: @Mike I don't understand how I can use your indications. I've not strong skills in javascript and the problem is complex for me. Can you answer my question with the pseudocode?

Comment: @Mike I've edited my question(EDIT 1). Using `forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` I've an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like @Mike is not around, I'm answering this.

When you calculate current view extent, you are transforming GeoJSON source coordinates from `EPSG:3857` to `EPSG:4326`, to use them for checking intersection with GeoJSON features. That's wrong since source coordinates are transformed automatically from original `EPSG:4326` to standard view `EPSG:3857` when GeoJSON is read into source.

It would be also better to use map's `moveend` to catch view extent change, since view's `change` events are called twice at every move/zoom event, once at the beginning and once at the end.

So your code could look something like:

```
map.on('moveend', function() {
  var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
  var polygonIntersection = [];

  polygonsSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function(feature) {
    polygonIntersection.push(feature);
  });
  
  console.log(polygonIntersection);
});
```

Comment: Why with your code I see an array fo 8 elements instead of 4? Every time I refresh the map the array has 8 elements

Comment: Since I don't see your complete code, I can't answer your comment. I tried the above code with your data and it worked.

Comment: Sorry it's a my mistake. Now I see the correct array length